# jEnv is messing with the VSCode Java Extension Pack

Tags: java, visual-studio-code

I recently got jEnv for managing Java versions on my Mac. (I normally use Java 12, my school uses Java 8) I noticed that after the installation and configuration, I opened VSCode with my work folder and I get 2 error messages saying that "Java 8 or more recent is required to run. Please download and install a recent JDK" (source from Java Language Support by Red Hat extension) and "Sorry, something went wrong activating IntelliCode support for Java. Please check the 'Language support for Java' and 'VS IntelliCode' output windows for details." (outside of Java Extension Pack but was affected anyways, source from Visual Studio IntelliCode Preview extension) I haven't changed the global Java version from the system version (Java 12) and even so, Java 12 and Java 8 should be supported. I don't know what's going on, but I assume it has something to do with jEnv.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the `jenv enable-plugin export` to enable the export plugin.
This should set the JAVA_HOME.

Ref: https://github.com/jenv/jenv